# Using multicol in the index

Tags: indexing, multicol

Can I use `multicol` to make the index split into two? I tried to use `multicol` but LaTeX keeps spitting some numbers in square brackets. I had to stop after the numbers count reached 15k.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
 \makeindex
\newcommand\alsoindex[1]{\index{#1}#1}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \printindex
\end{multicols}

\chapter*{प्रथमाध्यायः}


\index*{धर्मक्षेत्रे कुरुक्षेत्रे} समवेता \index*{युयुत्सव:} । \\
\index*{मामका:} पाण्डावश्चैव \index*{किमकुर्वत सञ्जय }॥ १ ॥
\end{document}
```

Comment: I fail to see how the example in your link is related to your question.

Comment: initially I clubbed both the questions, but then someone told me to make a separate questions. so I did giving the link to minimal example.

Comment: But the example does not "spit[...] some numbers". Please provide an example that actually shows the behaviour you describe.

Comment: i edited my question. I just realized after posting this question, would it be easier to split the page into two and use index on that split page rather than using multi-column.

Comment: By default, `\printindex` uses `\twocolumn` which shouldn't be used inside a `multicols` environment. I don't have the Devanagiri font, but replacing it with "Latin" letters doesn't result in the behaviour you describe. Also, what does "make the index split into two" mean?

Comment: @lockstep - I did not know that index by default uses two column. "Split in two" meaning the page should be in two page mode. If index does that by default then sorry for asking this question.

Comment: Just a guess: Do you want balanced columns? Try to load my `idxlayout` package (and remove the `multicols` environment).

Comment: @lockstep - Yes I would like to use balanced columns and if possible I want to add chapter name to the index columns as well. But don't know how to do it, should I start another question. I am looking at the     \idxlayout options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `\printindex` uses `\twocolumn` which shouldn't be used inside a `multicols` environment. If you aim at balanced columns, use my [`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) package. (Since version 0.4b, `idxlayout` is compatible with the `index` package.)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{index}
\makeindex

\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{foo}\index{foo}

\index*{aa} bb \index*{cc}

\index*{dd} ee \index*{ff}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, would it be possible to include the chapter name between the index item and page number. should I start a new question for it. If you say its possible then I will start a new question.

Comment: @Aku: Special formats for index entries should be possible. Please ask a new question and describe exactly how the entries should look like. (Adding the chapter name to *every* entry is rather unusual.) Also, don't use special fonts if the question isn't related to them.